# Changing a Site Title without HTML Element or jQuery

Tags: jquery, seo

I want to change my page/site title, but I don't have access to all of my HTML code (including title) on the online platform I'm using.

I've used this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(document).attr('title', 'Whatever you want');     
    });
</script>
```

But I've heard that this change is not SEO-friendly. Is that true? And what can I do instead?

Comment: Yes, it's not SEO-friendly. You should change the HTML.

Comment: It's not SEO friendly because the search engines will continue to see the original title as the title for the page.

Comment: if you're trying to work with a web platform that doesn't allow you to change the page title, then you need to find a better web platform. That's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the web platform that I'm required to use. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be SEO-friendly, you have to change it in the HTML.

If your "platform" comes with a CMS, there should be an option to set up page titles.

Comment: I am using XSLT to generate a dynamic hidden field which I want to use it in the title.